# Eclipse : Error While Running the Program

Tags: eclipse, macos

[image]

Kindly help me to resolve the following points: 
- How to see the error?
- as I'm writing c code : the standard text colour for header files, variable types etc .. not able to see.

Please help me to resolve the same.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should include source directly in your question description instead of attaching an image

Comment: @ketan can help me now please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have just called your file `Printf` (with no file extension) Eclipse does not know that it is a C program and has just opened the plain text editor.

Rename your file to be `Printf.c` (add the `.c` file extension). Eclipse uses the file extension to determine what sort of file you are using.

Since you have already opened this file using the plain text editor you will have to right click on the file and choose 'Open with` and select the C editor. You only have to do this once as Eclipse will remember your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the apt solution. Now I'm trying to run the same .. error is coming "Binary Not Found" Please help.

Comment: You should accept this answer (click the tick box) and then ask a new question about your new problem. I can't help with actual C problems.

Comment: When I'm trying to build my project file .. I'm getting this following error "'Building workspace' has encountered an error" : Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'CTraining'.
java.lang.NullPointerException" How to resolve? Please help!

Comment: No, as I said I don't know anything about the C development parts of Eclipse